# Here I am trying to store data in text file in Swift4 but it's not working

Tags: swift, xcode, file

Here I am just trying to insert a testing string to file but its not writing anything and even not showing me any error.

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var task: UITextField!

    @IBAction func addTaskClicked(_ sender: Any) {

        if(task.text != ""){
            todo.append(task.text!)
            task.text = ""
            var newString = "Testing"
            do {
                try newString.write(to: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "todoList", withExtension: "txt")!, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            }catch let error as NSError{
                print("\(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the error says ??

Comment: You cannot write into the application bundle at runtime because it's read-only

Comment: Formatting note for future questions: the `\`\`\`` has to be on its own line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't do that, if you need to save a string you could connect to a database/api or you can save stuff in the user default:

```
    let defaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    defaults.set("what you want to save", forKey: "key")
```

and you get it back like this:+

*Edited thanks @vadian*

```
    if let data = defaults.object(forKey: "key") {
        //do whatever you need to do
    }
```

i really don't think that writing stuff in a file is the best approach for making a TODO list anyway, its gonna be more annoying to do anything with the stored info than it should be.